# How to copy DataGrid from C# Windows Forms to SAP Crystal Report for VS 2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have a data grid and i want to make my reports free of data base, as the database result once brought in c# data grid, i want to use its attributes and collection into crystal report,

I am attaching an image of a sample data grid
[image]

I want to convert this grid to as it is in crystal report sap 2010.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Regards
Atif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to have the datagrid control itself be rendered on a Crystal Report. You can use the Crystal Report equivalent of the datagrid and simply use the dataset you are using to populate the datagrid.

Here is a thread that talks about what you are trying to do
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vscrystalreports/thread/d7a0ae9b-e09e-4fe8-ba7f-1563715234d0